# My asp.net project with MVC css isnt working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

here is my index file, whenever I run it the css doesnt work. I am kinda certain that I put the correct reference link from my css file. But I dont know why it doesnt really work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Views/Control_calci/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="calculator" name="calc">
            <input class="value" type="text" name="txt" readonly="">
            <span class="num clear" onclick="document.calc.txt.value =''">c</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='/'">/</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='*'">x</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='7'">7</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='8'">8</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='9'">9</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='-'">-</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='4'">4</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='5'">5</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='6'">6</span>
            <span class="num plus" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='+'">+</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='3'">3</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='2'">2</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='1'">1</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='00'">00</span>
            <span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value +='.'">.</span>
            <span class="num equal" onclick="document.calc.txt.value = eval(calc.txt.value)">=</span>
    
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is my css file. when I run the code it should look like a calculator, but when I run my project it doesnt apply the css.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*
{
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       box-sizing:border-box;
       font-family: 'Poppins' , sans-serif;
}

body
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height:100vh;
    background: #091921;
}
.calculator
{
    position:relative;
    display:grid;
}
.calculator .value
{
    grid-column: span 4;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.calculator span
{
    display:grid;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#0c2835;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.calculator span:active
{
    background: #74ff3b;
    color: #111;
}
.calculator span.clear
{
    grid-column: span 2;
    width: 120px;
    background: #ff3077;
}
.calculator span.plus
{
    grid-row: span 2;
    height: 120px;
}
.calculator span.equal
{
    background: #03b1ff;

}
```

Comment: Is your css somewhere stored under the wwwroot folder?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by putting the css file inside the index file but I still have a problem. all the buttons isnt aligned as it should[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2SIC.png)